# SailsJs Invalid module error

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

After I installed `lodash` or async plug-ins,
Console shows those error messages when I launch **sails.js**.
but I don't know what cause those error messages.

I need to solve this problem. please anyone help me.

```
error: A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load!

error: Error: Invalid module:[object Object]

at /Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:83:15

at forOwn (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:2105:15)

at Function.forEach (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3302:9)

at buildDictionary (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:74:4)

at Function.module.exports.aggregate (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:190:9)

at Array.loadOtherConfigFiles [as 0] (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:164:27)

at /Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:459:38

at Array.forEach (native)

at _each (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)

at Object.async.auto (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:430:9) [Error: Invalid module:[object Object]]

error: Error: Invalid module:[object Object]

at /Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:83:15

at forOwn (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:2105:15)

at Function.forEach (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3302:9)

at buildDictionary (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:74:4)

at Function.module.exports.aggregate (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:190:9)

at Array.loadOtherConfigFiles [as 0] (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:164:27)

at /Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:459:38

at Array.forEach (native)

at _each (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)

at Object.async.auto (/Users/johndo/github/sails/testProject/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:430:9) [Error: Invalid module:[object Object]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's experiencing an error while parsing your configuration files. Try rolling back your changes.

Also, lodash and async come as globals in sails, so you don't need to install them. Just go to config/globals and uncomment _(lodash). That might fix your problem, as maybe sails is having a conflict between its installed version and yours.

Comment: thank you for your advise aclave1! yes you right. I rebuilt my sails project again and it works now! thank you again.